# Modifying Parameters in a large codebase

Tags: c#

I am tasked with modifying functionality of an existing method. This method reads a config.xml file and generates an endpoint. This method is called by 70 other methods to generate a rest based call. I have to make this method generate potentially 2 endpoints depending on where we are in the migration process. The problem is how do I change the 70 other methods to accept 2 possible parameters? Is there an easy way to achieve this without having to touch the 70 methods calling the one method I am modifying? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a default value to a parameter. So if you've for example this method:

```
public string ShowName(string firstName){}
```

And you want to add an optional parameter you could do:

```
public string ShowName(string firstName, string lastName = String.empty){}
```

Comment: Thats a good suggestion to take care of the potential for 2 parameters but, Im looking for a way to not have to modify 70 methods.